# How to forward portsbon a USB tethered connection?

Tags: usb, networking, internet, usb-tethering

I'm using a USB tethered connection from my phone to my PC, I'd like to know if there's any way I can forward ports through this tethered connection, so that I'm able to play games that uses peer-to-peer.

Keep in mind I have Android v7.x.x and Windows 7.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to open up a port on your mobile connection to allow incoming connections, correct? Unfortunately nearly every mobile network provider uses carrier-grande-NAT (CG-NAT) which means you don't get a public IP and thus can not open any ports. A public IPv4 address usually requires a special business data-plan, or a mobile network provider that provides you a public IPv6 address but that would require that the game is also IPv6 ready.

Comment: How can I check whether I have a public IPv4/6 public address?

Comment: You can check your public IPs using certain web-sites and services like https://whatsmyip.com and compare it to your local IP. Alternatively there are apps that query the public IP and show it in the app. E.g. this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.webprovider.whatismyipaddress

Comment: Cool, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Okay so whatsmyip.com Is giving me two Ip addresses namely a public ipv4 address and a LAN IP address and they're different from each other.                                                                      So another question is: How do I forward ports? Do I do it through my phone or through my PC? And which address (Public ipv4 or LAN IP) must I use to do so? Should I forward ports through my android phone using an app like Fwd or Port Knocker, and if so how? And which app is best to use for port forwarding on android?

Comment: If you open the web page directly on your phone with only mobile data activated and you are getting different IPs then you don't have a public IP. Thus opening or forwarding ports is useless as a CG-NET is used (see my first comment).